# Error running mongod command in Tokumx

Tags: mongodb, tokumx

I am trying to install Tokumx mongodb inside ubuntu VM using Putty.
I have followed all the steps to install tokuMX mongodb from the link http://docs.tokutek.com/tokumx/tokumx-installation.html
I have created /data/db folder inside root and given permission.
when I ran mongod command , I got an error -> this is the screenshot.
[image: Error]

It creates mongod.lock file inside data folder , I tried deleting that file and ran but got the same error. 
How to fix it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the error message, you have to disable the transparent huge pages before launching mongod.

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

On Red Hat:

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/enabled
```

Comment: Tried but got an error =>> lnt@ubuntu:/opt/tokumx-2.0.0-linux-x86_64$ sudo echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled -bash: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled: Permission denied

Comment: Run the command as root. To be root, first assign a password to root with "sudo passwd". Then use "su -" to become root and run the command again.